# Spring Boot Thymeleaf won't resolve template

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm having an issue getting my spring boot application to load up my simple webpage.
I have copied the examples that were provided [here](https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/Examples.html#layouts) and implemented them in the templates directory
I keep getting this error

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Here is a look at the file directory

[image]

This is everything that's in the controller class

```
package com.example.cloud_computing_project;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    private String OpenMainPage() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Here is what the build.gradle looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.RC2")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    //implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have looked around and as far as I can tell, the files are right, the location of the files are right, and the getmapping pointing to the location is right. Only thing I can see being wrong is that I might be missing a dependancy in my build.gradle

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated thank you.

Comment: try add `spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML` into properties file

Comment: @sovannarithcheav this unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Does the console say something error or not?

Comment: @sovannarithcheav it gave me the same error that I was getting before.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31946688/10383493

Comment: Do you have _any_ `application.properties` or `application.yml`?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- yes I have it under the resources directory. You can see that in the directory listing picture provided above

Comment: You did not include it in your question. It is part of the code.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- sorry, I misunderstood what you meant. I do technically have a application.properties file but it is empty. I attempted to put the first comments suggestion in there but it didn't work so I removed it.

Comment: Add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.
Also please post the contents of index.html and layout.html

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot Thymeleaf Starter 2.0 onwards you need to explicitly include ultraq thymeleaf layout dialect dependency. 
In Maven it would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This did not help the issue that I posted about (see my posted answer) but it did help with the layout not working when I did get it running.

Answer (score 0):

I started to get curious if anything else wasn't working. So I included "server.port=8081" in the application.properties file. This did not take when I ran it. With this in mind, and that the output is stating it can't find the templates folder under classpath:/ I started to wonder if somehow the defaults were being overwritten by something.

I did not alter any configurations at all. The only thing I did was configure the build.gradle to import dependencies and that was it.

I found a forum that suggested to run it with the gradle.Tasks.Application.bootRun

This did fix the issues I was having. It was now finding the templates folder and loading my index.html file. It also was using the application.properties file. However, since this wasn't being built and ran by IntelliJ it wasn't color-coding the output.

According to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847452/intellij-ultimate-ignores-spring-boot-application-properties) the suggested fix was to re-import the project.

I had already pushed my project to a git repository and the .gitignore doesn't push any of the files that could cause this issue. So I deleted my entire working directory and then cloned the pushed repository.

**IT WORKED**! Everything is working fine now. application.properties is working and my HTML files are being loaded successfully under /src/main/resources/templates

Also thanks to @MohamedSanaulla for his suggestion on layout dialect dependency. I was having trouble with that too until I added the implementation in gradle.